# Custom field to upload files(image) in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Is there any way to add a custom field that can accept an image file.

Just like:

```
<input type="file" name="doctor_dp"></input>
```

But the above code is not working for WordPress... Please help.

Comment: https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/image/

Comment: go with advanced custom fields plugin

Comment: @RamNiwasSharma Thanks, it`s a little bit complicated but I will give it a go. :-)

Comment: @charankumar i don`t want to use plugin for that i have almost done 85% with all the work this is the only thing i am stucked in.

Comment: how come basic html tag is not working in wordpress, <input type="file" name="doctor_dp" />

Comment: @charankumar Yeah not working as expected. It`s not fetching the data after page updated.

update_post_meta($post->ID, "doctor_dp", @$_POST["doctor_dp"]);

This code is not working with this field. :-(

Answer (score 0):

If you are working on a custom post type it's always better to go with [Advanced Custom Field Plugin](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/)

Since you have mentioned your `input` tag try this

`<input type="file" name="myImage" accept="image/x-png,image/gif,image/jpeg" />`

or simply

`<input type="file" name="myImage" accept="image/*" />`